# How to get innermost text of a tag with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html element:

```
<blockquote class="abstract">
<span class="descriptor"> abstract</span>
Abstract text goes here
</blockquote>
```

I am interested in getting the "abstarct text...". I have tried the following approaches in python and beautifulsoup.

```
abstract=soup.find('blockquote', {"class":'abstract mathjax'})
```

the above gets to the  correctly (I checked printing it). But none of the following suceeds at getting the text:

```
print abstract.text
print abstract.find(text=True)
print abstract.get_text()
```

Any clues? Thank you very much in advance,

Gabriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find both `abstract` and `mathjax`. Try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<blockquote class="abstract">
<span class="descriptor"> abstract</span>
Abstract text goes here
</blockquote>"""    

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
abstract = soup.find('blockquote', class_='abstract')
abstract.span.extract()   # Remove span element
print abstract.text
```

Which would print:

```
Abstract text goes here
```